# I am making a simple password generator using Python and nothing happens when I run it but I also see no errors. What did I do wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to build a simple password generator that takes user inputs and based on answers adds character lists to a larger list that can then randomly generate a password. I am not sure where I went wrong with it. I know there are probably more efficient ways of doing this but I need to use multiple lists and loops for my assignment. I am not getting any errors but nothing happens when I run it. Thank you in advance for helping me.

```
# import random generator module
import random

# creates three lists: letters, digits, and symbols 
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'm', 'n','o', 'p', 'q',  'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'p', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'] 
digits = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'] 
symbols = ['!', '@', '#', '"', '$', '%', '&', "'", '(', ')', '*', '+', ',', '-', '.', '/', ':', ';', '<', '>', '=', '?', '[', ']', '^', '_', '`', '{', '}', '|', "~"]
password = []

# This gets the desired length for the password from the user
def user_password_length():
    pw_length = input("Hello! How long would you like your password to be?: ")
    return int(pw_length)

#This asks if the user wants to include letters, and adds it to password list if they do

def user_letters_choice():
  include_letters = input("Would you like to include letters in your password? Answer yes or no:  ")
  if include_letters == "yes":
    password.extend(letters)
    return password
  elif include_letters == "no":
    pass
  else:
    print("Make sure your input is lowercase yes or no!") 

#This asks if user wants to include digits in their password and adds it to password list if they do
def user_digits_choice():
  include_digits = input("Would you like to include digits in your password? Answer yes or no: ")
  if include_digits == "yes":
    password.extend(digits)
    return password
  elif include_digits == "no":
    pass
  else:
    print("Make sure your input is lowercase yes or no!") 

# This asks if users want to include symbols in their password and adds it to password list if they do

def user_symbols_choice():
  include_symbols = input("Would you like to include symbols in your password? Answer yes or no: ")
  if include_symbols == "yes":
    password.extend(symbols)
    return password
  elif include_symbols == "no":
    pass
  else:
    print("Make sure your input is lowercase yes or no!") 

# tells script to run x number of times based on user's chosen length for their password and then randomly chooses x amount of characters from the list of available characters in password
def password_generator(pw_length):
  for x in range(pw_length):
    user_pw = random.choice(password)
    print(user_pw)
```

Comment: Is this all the code? You never appear to call the functions.

Answer (score 1):

You've got your methods written, now you need to structure how these methods are used. When you define a method, that doesn't also call the method. To call a method you've created, you simply call the method name with parenthesis. For example, here's a hypothetical method definition:

```
def doSomething(name):
    print("hi %s" % name)
```

Now to call this function in your code, you call it like this:

```
doSomething("steve")
```

Answer (score 0):

functions works unless they have called. first you have to run functions in order you know then you have proper answer.
for example
no indent `user_password_length()` will call 'user_password_length' function in your code. good luck